# SAS PROC SORT ERROR: No disk space is available for the write operation

Tags: sas

I have a database whose size after importing in SAS is around 600mb.

( I use `OPTIONS COMPRESS = YES` at start of my program)

Then I derive some columns/variables and get a final database of size around 800 mb

Final Database has `1929743 observations`

**What I want**

I want to sort the data in `descending` order of `PUBLICATION_DATE` for each record in column `ITEM` in my final database

**My code so far**

```
        PROC SORT DATA=newdb.access_db OUT= newdb.access_sorted; 
        BY ITEM DESCENDING PUBLICATION_DATE;
        RUN;
```

The error which I am getting

```
ERROR: No disk space is available for the write operation.  Filename =
       C:\Users\AB364273\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary
       Files\SAS_util00010000204C_A00DVDPCSAS2007\ut204C000008.utl.
ERROR: Failure while attempting to write page 134 of sorted run 11.
ERROR: Failure while attempting to write page 40544 to utility file 1.
ERROR: Failure encountered while creating initial set of sorted runs.
ERROR: Failure encountered during external sort.
ERROR: Sort execution failure.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: There were 1244486 observations read from the data set
      NEWDB.ACCESS_DB.
WARNING: The data set NEWDB.ACCESS_SORTED may be incomplete.  When this step was
         stopped there were 0 observations and 57 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT used (Total process time):
      real time           2:17.20
      cpu time            14.66 seconds
```

My database is not so large that error like no disk space should appear.

Also I have a lot of space on my hard disk( around 500 GB on drive where I am storing the database using `libname` and 8 GB on C Drive)

I have RAM of 4GB

So with all this I am not getting the reason that why this error is appearing and any way I can get the desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 8GB free on C drive, then that is likely your problem.

Sorting happens in a temporary (scratch) file, and that file can be up to *three times* as large as the original file. It also has to be on *uncompressed* data, for obvious reasons.  As such, if your uncompressed file is say 3-4 GB in size, it wouldn't be sortable on the 8GB drive.

You can solve this by either moving your work location to a larger drive (or freeing up space), or by using the TAGSORT option, which reduces the utility file usage at the cost of speed (See [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146878.htm) for more details).

You also could request it from the database sorted; this is what I'd recommend if you're sorting by fields in the database (not by modified fields).  You don't even have to use `proc sort` in most cases; if the database is in a libname `db`:

```
data access_sorted;
  set db.access_db_Table;
  by item descending publication_date;
run;
```

That will work just fine and will ask for it in sorted order directly from the database.

Comment: If I go with sorting it in database will my dervied column will also get correspondingly sorted.(The fields that I am using for sorting are not derived fields) but asking this just to make sure when sorting happens for a row all the fields (original and derived both) gets  sorted properly Sorry if this is a very basic question

Comment: @Rookie_123 That shouldn't be an issue, if I understand you right.  Assuming your derived fields are just like `x=y*z+45` or whatever, you can do that directly in the data step where you pull it down, or in a later one, and it shouldn't be a problem.  If you're merging another dataset on to get the derived fields, obviously that other dataset has to be sorted correctly as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I has given me all possible alternatives to look into

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was something @Joe said, that your work library location is lacking space even if overall you have space.
I don't know the answer to this but is an ORDER BY statement in PROC SQL less expensive in terms of the temporary memory required? You could try it at least.

Comment: ORDER BY is going to just implement a sort, unfortunately, for such a big dataset.